# Interest not updating

Tags: java

It is meant to calculate interest and then put that into a table with years, interest, and new balance. For some reason the interest is not being calculated correctly and is not updating.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class Interest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        printIntro();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter initial balance: ");
        int balanceAmount = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter interest rate: ");
        double interestRate = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
        int years = input.nextInt();
        printTable(years, balanceAmount, interestRate);


    }  

    public static double calcInterest(double balanceAmount, double interestRate, double years) 
    {
        double interest = balanceAmount * Math.pow((1 + interestRate/100),years);
        return interest;
    }

    public static void printRow(int rowNum, double balanceAmount, double interestRate)
    {
        System.out.println(rowNum + "\t" + balanceAmount + "\t" + "\t" + interestRate + "\t" + "\t" + (balanceAmount + interestRate));
        //balanceAmount = (balanceAmount + interestRate);
    }

    public static void printTable(int numRows, double balanceAmount, double interestRate)
    {
        System.out.println("Year" + "\t" + "Balance" + "\t" + "\t" + "Interest" + "\t" + "New Balance");
         System.out.println("----" + "\t" + "-------" + "\t" + "\t" + "--------" + "\t" + "-----------");

         for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) 
            {
                printRow(i, balanceAmount, interestRate);
                balanceAmount = (balanceAmount + interestRate);
            }
    }

    public static void printIntro()
    {
        System.out.println("This program will calculate the interest "
                + "earned on a deposit over a certain amount of years.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling `calcInterest` at all

Comment: I am confused on where to call it though

Comment: BalanceAmount = balanceAmount + calcInterest(balanceAmount, interestRate, 1);

Answer (score 0):

You should call your business logic to calculate interest as per your business requirement. That totaly depend on your business requirement.

Though for program specific it seems that You need to call your calcInterest  method in printTable method, before you call your printRow method as below:

```
public static void printTable( final int numRows, double balanceAmount, final double interestRate ) {
        System.out.println( "Year" + "\t" + "Balance" + "\t" + "\t" + "Interest" + "\t" + "New Balance" );
        System.out.println( "----" + "\t" + "-------" + "\t" + "\t" + "--------" + "\t" + "-----------" );

        for ( int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++ ) {
            double interest = calcInterest( balanceAmount, interestRate, 1 );
            printRow( i, balanceAmount, interest );
            balanceAmount = ( balanceAmount + interest );
        }
    }
```

Also your formula to calculate interest is wrong. it should be

```
 double interest = balanceAmount * Math.pow( ( 1 + interestRate / 100 ), years )-balanceAmount;
```

It will give out put as below:

This program will calculate the interest earned on a deposit over a certain amount of years.

This program will calculate the interest earned on a deposit over a certain amount of years.

`Enter initial balance: 100
Enter interest rate: 10
Enter the number of years: 3
Year    Balance             Interest                New Balance
----    -------             --------                -----------
1   100.0                   10.000000000000014      110.00000000000001
2   110.00000000000001      23.100000000000037      133.10000000000005
3   133.10000000000005      44.05610000000007       177.15610000000012`

Comment: yeah but then this is doubling balance and adding interest instead of just adding interest to balance

Comment: So your business logic to calculate interest is wrong, you need to look into it as well.

Comment: @robertleshi check update in my answer, your formula to calculate interest is wrong

Comment: Ok i fixed some stuff but now I have a final problem and it is the balance is adding 10 (in your case with a rate of 10) instead of using the new balance

Comment: @robertleshi see printtable method, you need following correction balanceAmount = ( balanceAmount + interest );

Answer (score -1):

You are not calling calcInterest.

You need to call that under the printRow method before the

```
System.out.println(rowNum + "\t" + balanceAmount + "\t" + "\t" + interestRate + "\t" + "\t" + (balanceAmount + interestRate));
```

line